# Syntax error with a simple Python import

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

My GF is trying to follow the [Udacity's Web Development course](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253) but she ran into a problem. And I can't solve it. It's just at the start when one has to create a "hello world" Python script that runs on AppEngine.

So, the files:

app.yaml:

```
application: focus-invention-298
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

helloworld.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

​import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, Udacity!')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

But, when I run the app (either trough the GUI launcher or with the dev_appserver.py) and open the app in the browser I get this error (in the console):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kaja/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/Kaja/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/Kaja/Documents/udacity/helloworld.py", line 3
    ​import webapp2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
INFO     2013-08-05 14:06:00,875 module.py:595] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2013-08-05 14:06:01,012 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kaja/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/Kaja/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/Kaja/Documents/udacity/helloworld.py", line 3
    ​import webapp2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

We are on OSX 10.8.4 and when I run python in the terminal it tells me I have 2.7.2 version installed. AppEngine launcher (or SDK) version is 1.8.2.

Anyone? I've tried so many things now without success that I really don't know what to do anymore (I'm not a python dev) and I really wanna make this thing work so my GF can continue learning :)

Comment: Has the file perhaps been saved with Windows line endings?

Comment: I should think not since she did all the work in Sublime on a Mac. But I'll check just to be sure.

Comment: It's a long shot; but there are characters *before* the `i` of `import` that are throwing off Python here.

Comment: It can't be line-endings; I've not been able to reproduce that exception on my Mac using `\r\n` line endings in a file.

Comment: Can you please run: `print repr(open('helloworld.py', 'rb').read(50))` and add the output to your question?

Comment: There seem to be some weird (invisible) characters in my file yes. Hmm, let me try getting rid of them.

Comment: What are the hex values for those 'weird' bytes?

Comment: Yep that was it. Dunno how that happened. She told me that she just copy/pasted the code into Sublime. Strange. Anyways, post this as an answer so I can accept it :) And thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are bytes *before* the `import` statement (unicode non-breaking whitespace characters are a prime candidate) that could cause this.

Check the first 50 bytes or so:

```
print repr(open('helloworld.py', 'rb').read(50))
```

If you see a sequence like `'\xc2\xa0'` then you have UTF-8 encoded non-breakable space characters in there, for example.

Comment: Cheers, I really don't know how they got in there. And it was \xc2 yes. Anyhow, my GF will now be able to continue her journey towards becoming as frustrated as we are with out tools :)

Comment: `\xc2` is a *leading* byte for a UTF8 sequence, it indicates another byte is part of the character. NBSP characters are often found in webpages indicating indentation (you usually do not want to wrap the line there), they are a nuisance.